# Getting App Maker to respect the order of a many-to-many relation

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm having some trouble getting App Maker to respect the order of a many-to-many relation.

Let's say I have two models:

Model 1 has an ID and a many-to-many relation to model 2 which also has an ID.

App maker generates three tables:

```
DESCRIBE model_1;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
DESCRIBE model_2;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
DESCRIBE model_1_Has_model_2;
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| parentModel1_fk  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| childModel2_fk   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now let's say I have a model_1 object with ID `1` and three model_2 objects with IDs `1, 2, 3`.  If I assign `model_1.childModel_2` to `[model_2_ID_1, model_2_ID_2]` the `model_1_Has_model_2` table will contain:

```
parentModel1_fk | childModel2_fk
--------------------------------
1               | 1
1               | 2
```

Now let's say I splice `model_1.childModel_2` using `model_1.childModel_2.splice(0, 1)` and then insert model_2 ID 3 in index 0 using `model_1.childModel_2.splice(0, 0, model_2_ID_3)`.  I would expect my table to contain the following:

```
parentModel1_fk | childModel2_fk
--------------------------------
1               | 3
1               | 1
```

However it contains the opposite:

```
parentModel1_fk | childModel2_fk
--------------------------------
1               | 1
1               | 3
```

Is there any way I can stop this behavior short of clearing the entire relation and then setting it to my new expected order?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. App Maker is just creating a new record, not rearranging the table. Otherwise it would have to edit all the records below the desired insertion point (which could be a prohibitively time consuming transaction). If this is the desired functionality, you'll have to do it manually.

I would seriously consider creating your own join table that will allow you to have additional columns, where you can store the desired sort order.